# IE9 throws JavaScript Error: SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'getComputedStyle' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript

Telrik.web.webresource.axd file thrown "SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'getComputedStyle' is null or undefined, not a Function object" error. It works properly for other browsers. can anyone please suggest how I handled it throw hardcoded.

Comment: We need to see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `getComputedStyle` is a JavaScript function used in modern browsers. It allows you to get dimensions from hidden elements for example.

That said, if your browser doesn't recognize the function, you need a polyfill to enhance your browser with this feature.

Normally a js library using this function should provide the polyfill. If this was not the case, add it yourself.

https://github.com/jonathantneal/Polyfills-for-IE8/blob/master/getComputedStyle.js

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have resolved the error but now it has broken my functionality,Now drag and drop feature is not working in my screen.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle). It's possible you're still missing other polyfills. Hard to tell without any other information. Any console messages?